# Linq2SQL inherited types and OfType query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, inheritance, datasource, oftype

I have a setup where I used Linq2SQL inheritance. To make queries easier, I expose the derived types in the DataContext as well, like the following:

```
public IQueryable<Derived> Derivations 
{
  get { return Bases.OfType<Derived>(); } // filter list on type
}
```

Calling this works perfectly, and I can see the SQL being correctly generated. The backing type is DataQuery<T>.

The problem comes in when I assigning this IEnumerable to a datasource (either a control or a BindingSource).

From what I can see, the DataQuery object is queried for an IListSource. And it happily supplies this. Then it proceeds to make a BindingList, which fails as the type parameter of the 2 arguments supplied (IEnumerable<Derived> and Table<Base>) does not match. It raises an exception of MissingMethod as the constructor cannot be found.

The simple workaround is just to call ToList() on the IQueryable<Derived> before assigning to the datasource and then it works, but this is quite tiring.

Any suggestions to handle this without 'loosing' the IQueryable?

Thanks

leppie

**UPDATE:**

The bug has now been reported to MS. More details [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=427574). Thanks Marc!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed. Looks like a bug to me; you should log it on [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/). The team [are fixing LINQ-to-SQL bugs](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/02/linq-to-sql-not-quite-dead-yet.html), so it might not be ignored. For now, use `.ToList()` etc.

Sample code:

```
using (var ctx = new MyDataContext())
{
    var qry = ctx.BaseEntities.OfType<DerivedEntity>();
    IListSource ls = (IListSource)qry;
    IList list = ls.GetList(); // boom
    /* Constructor on type
       'System.Data.Linq.Provider.DataBindingList`1[snip]'
       not found.*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks  :)  Hehe, I took the long investigative route via Reflector  :)

Comment: @leppie - alas, I'm already painfully familiar with the route such bindings take...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (still not fixed MS guys!).

To keep the IQueryable I did a `.Cast<object>()` when assigning to the datasource (i use it to output a xls file from any L2S table i want in a DynamicData website).